# Lithium and validating login form (without model) - how?

Tags: php, lithium

Is there any way to use Validator on login form from [Simple Authentication in Lithium](http://lithify.me/docs/manual/auth/simple-authentication.wiki) tutorial. I know that it is better to use validation in model, but with login form there's no model, so, as I understand, I need to use Validator in the SessionsController, but I don't know how to do it (

What I am trying to do is in SessionsController:

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;
use lithium\security\Auth;
use lithium\storage\Session;
use lithium\util\Validator;

class SessionsController extends \lithium\action\Controller {

private $rules = array(
    'password' => array(
        array('notEmpty', 'message' => 'password is empty'),
    ),
    'email' => array(
        array('notEmpty', 'message' => 'email is empty'),
        array('email', 'message' => 'email is not valid')
    )
);

public function add() {
    if ($this->request->data && Auth::check('default', $this->request)) {
        return $this->redirect('/');
    }
    // Handle failed authentication attempts
    $errors = Validator::check($this->request->data, $this->rules);
    return compact('errors');
}

public function delete() {
    Auth::clear('default');
    return $this->redirect('/');
}

/* ... */
}
```

and I'm expect that after empty form was sent, it will be rendered with errors, like in user creation from tutorial. But there are no errors showed, just login form again. Can I ever validate forms without models and how to do it in Lithium?

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Why you don't have a Users and/or Sessions Model? How do you want to check the password or the email?

Comment: I have Users model. What I am trying to do is check input in login form and if email or password are empty - display errors under input boxes of the form, like in user creation tutorial. Why do I need model here?

Comment: The validation rules are bound to the model entity (a user). The controller role is only for getting incoming data (from a form POST), call your models which holds your business rules, and render a response (a view, a file or plain text or anything else). In your case here, it's easier to check if $this->request->data['password'] is empty or not.Stop by IRC #li3 if you need help and examples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The errors rendered in the form are bound to an entity, which is bound to the form when you create it with `$this->form->create($user)`. In this case only, the errors are displayed thanks to the form helper automatically.

If your need is to check, in the controller, the incoming data, you can check `$this->request->data['password']` and return errors that you need to handle by yourself in the form view (with `if (!empty($errors))` for example)

Comment: Yea! I just get it. Thank you for showing me the way! I've done it by sending Entity with errors() to Form helper after login fails and now it works like a charm. It's true, that all documentation lays in Lithium's source code. Thank you again! Sorry that I can't vote - not enough rep.